# Mockito with jUnit ParallelComputer

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing integration test for a spring boot controller for concurrent access of APIs. I want to run these tests in parallel using a common setup. I looked at jUnit ParallelComputer but couldn't find a way to create a common setup. Even if I find a way to do the common setup the @Autowired variables are not getting instantiated, they remain null. Am I missing something?

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ParallelComputerTest {

@Test  
   public void test() {     
      Class[] cls={ParallelTest1.class};  

      //Parallel all methods in all classes  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), cls);     
   } 
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ParallelTest1 {  

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private someClass;

    @Test public void a(){
       //someClass and mockMvc is null here
       //do something
    }  
    @Test public void b(){}  
}
```

Why is mockMvc and the other classes I @Autowired null?

I need a way to spin up the server, do some common setup and run the tests in parallel.